# Office 365 REST API - User Activity

Tags: rest, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

In Azure AD you can see the activity and devices that have been used to access a user account.

Example:

[image]

Is it possible to query this information via the Microsoft Graph API?  I've been unable to locate an API call that accomplishes this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible to find this information via Microsoft Graph API.

You can use Device Entity which represents a device registered in the directory. It inherits this information related to Device from DirectoryObject.

You can use **deviceOSType** for type of operating system on the device.
**deviceOSVersion** for the version of the operating system on the device.

Similarly, you can use Contact Entity which gives information related to place, physical office address and other things.

For more details refer to [API Catalog for Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog.)

Comment: I believe Device Entity is only for registered devices though, the list of devices I'm showing isn't necessarily registered.

Comment: @DouglasPlumley As you must be knowing that Office APIs are still in development phase, Right now there is no way to get list of devices that ain't registered. If something comes along, I would love to share it.